# "He is in the horizontal position", "supine", which expression is more clear and idiomatic?

Tags: meaning, expressions

This post is derived from this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/236418/103381).

Consider the guy pointed out by red circle the following image (img_1),

[image]

which expression in the following is more clear and idiomatic?

1. He is in the horizontal position.
2. He's supine.

Answer (score 1):

All of the people in the picture are in **a** horizontal position, so I don't think that option 1 describes his position completely.

The word **[supine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supine)** is not very widely used: the Cambridge Dictionary describes it as **formal**. I knew that it meany lying down, but I was surprised to find that it does additionally mean "lying on your back, looking up". I suspect that I'm not the only one that doesn't know this. For this reason, I don't think that option 1 is very useful either.

A more idiomatic way of describing this would be:

> He is lying on his back

Comment: The opposite of _supine_ is _prone_ (lying face down), but neither would be used in everyday speech.

Comment: @KateBunting So, both "lying face down" and "lying face up" would be used in everyday speech and everyone can understand readily, right?

Comment: @zghqh Yes - or _lying on his back_ as JavaLatte suggests.